# How to delete div with jQuery that is dynamically created with unique id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to delete div with jQuery that is dynamically created with unique id?

 i am trying to use below code but it is not working. 

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="div-roomcart" id="divOAK1AKL">
  <div class="div-roomcart-hotel">
    <div class="div-roomcart-hotelname">Eden Park Bed And Breakfast</div>
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomtype">Single Standard</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-roomcart-room">
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomprice">14058.26</div>
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomaction">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remove" class="btnbook" onclick="removeroom(divOAK1AKL)">
    </div>
</div>
```

there will be multiple of div which i have to delete on **onclick="removeroom(code)"** this is a jQuery function below is the jQuery Code


**jQuery Code in removeroom.js**

```
function removeroom(hotelcode){
   $("'#"+hotelcode"'").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
function removeroom(hotelcode){
   $("#" + hotelcode).remove();
}
```

or

just pass the perameter with selector

like

```
 removeroom("#hotelcode"); // calling function hare.

 function removeroom(hotelcode){
    $(hotelcode).remove();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to wrap the selector once again with single quotes,

```
function removeroom(hotelcode){
   $("#" + hotelcode).remove();
}
```

That will make the selector invalid. Also you can use an dedicated event handler for it rather than using an `inline event` handler. Inline event handler has more disadvantages, and the most important one from that is maintenance.

Comment: yes it is woking but it is not fixed that hotelcode will be int it can be string.

Comment: @AjayKumar When you concatenate a number with a string, then it will become a string. So you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: it is not woking when hotelcode going to be string.

Comment: @AjayKumar ok at that time, how your html looks like?

Comment: @AjayKumar Then your html should be like `onclick="removeroom('divOAK1AKL')">` If you do not give like that then reference error will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

without Jquery,

```js
function removeroom(hotelCode) {
  typeof hotelCode == 'object' ? hotelCode.remove() : document.getElementById(hotelCode.toString()).remove();


}
```

```html
<div class="div-roomcart" id="divOAK1AKL">
  <div class="div-roomcart-hotel">
    <div class="div-roomcart-hotelname">Eden Park Bed And Breakfast</div>
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomtype">Single Standard</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div-roomcart-room">
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomprice">14058.26</div>
    <div class="div-roomcart-roomaction">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Remove" class="btnbook" onclick="removeroom('divOAK1AKL')">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: can you check it again it is not woking when hotelcode is going to be string